# File types related to R

Tags: r, rstudio, dataformat

For a project I need an overview of most commonly used files types related to R, so this includes R files and input data types.

R-files

- .R
- .Rproj

Data

- .CSV
- .DAT
- .TXT

  Which commonly used file types am I missing?

Comment: Likely this will get closed but .Rmd, .Rnw, .Rd, .rda and .RData are a few more.

Comment: .XML, .html.  Review of the "external" data types handled by the foreign package.

Answer (score 1):

I'd add .dbf too. Depending on the applications, they're image files like .jpg .img .tif. If you work with spatial features you might wanna consider .shp, .kml...